Calculating mirror size for a teleprompter
I'm trying to calculate the required size of a mirror for a teleprompter application. The goal is to use the smallest possible mirror while still capturing the full image.
It's a straightforward setup, with an image laying flat, a mirror of length y at a 45 degree angle. It is offset a variable distance x away from the image.

My question is does y need to cover the entire distance over the image, like above?
Or can it be smaller, like below?

If it can be smaller, is there a formulaic way to calculate the required minimum y?
Thank you in advance.

The mirror should really be at least as large as the screen projecting the image, and ideally a bit larger.  If it's smaller, it will diminish the range at which the teleprompter screen can be fully seen.
Assuming for simplicity that the mirror makes a 45° angle with the vertical.  The mirror will create a virtual image of the screen that is vertical and positioned "behind" the mirror.  For all intents and purposes, you can imagine that you are looking at this "virtual image" through a "window" with the same size and shape of as the mirror.

To use this as a teleprompter, you need to be able to see the entirety of this virtual image.  You can figure this out by tracing the rays that are emitted from the top and bottom of the virtual image and pass through the top and bottom of the "window" (i.e., the mirror.)  For example, if the mirror is the same horizontal size as the screen, then anywhere in the blue shaded region can see the top of the virtual image:

And anywhere in the red shaded region can see the bottom of the virtual image:

So we can combine these two to visualize the region of space over which the entire virtual image can be seen;  it will be the purple region where the red and blue overlap:

When you change the size of the mirror, it changes the size of the "window" you're looking through, but it does not change the size of the virtual image.  That means if you make the mirror smaller than the screen, it will also be smaller than the virtual image, and someone that's too far away will not be able to see the top and bottom of the virtual image at the same time.  Here's an extreme example of this:

Conversely, if the mirror is larger than the screen, there will be a wider range of angles at which the entirety of the virtual image can be seen:

This is better for a teleprompter, since it allows the speaker to move their head and/or body a bit while still being able to see the image.  If the mirror and the virtual image are exactly the same size, then there's only a narrow "beam", with the same width as the screen itself, where the entire screen will be visible;  and the speaker would have to remain unnaturally still while speaking if they wanted to stay in that "beam".
Similar diagrams can be constructed if the mirror is not at a 45° angle with the horizontal, though in that case the virtual image will not be vertical and figuring out its location is a bit trickier.  The basic principles will remain the same, though.

Thank you for this answer! It clarified the different factors at play. And the visualizations specifically were very helpful.

Is it correct to say the image brightness will be the same no matter where you are in the visible "eye box"?

@Sohil Sathe:  The image's brightness at different viewing angles will be constant to the same extent that the screen's brightness is constant at different viewing angles.  Most likely it won't be a problem unless your screen projects light in an unusually narrow angular range.
